# PL/SQL Como consolidar as linhas da tabela a seguir somando a coluna "VALOR" e mantendo as informações das demais colunas?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

[IMAGEM DA TABELA ORIGINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAhtI.png)

Estou precisando consolidar as linhas da tabela somando a coluna "VALOR" e mantendo as informações das demais colunas. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar com essa questão?

Preciso que a tabela saia dessa forma:

[TABELA DESEJADA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5SR1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi.

Eu creio que você precisa user o SUM nas colunas de valor e agrupar pela outras colunas da tabela que você deseja segmentar.

Algo semelhante a isso que eu fiz (não testei):

```
SELECT
b.codeli,
b.cliente,
sum(a.saldolimite) saldolimite,
sum(a.saldodisponiível) saldodisponiível,
sum(c.valor) valor,
c.codusur,
Gc.codsupervisor,
c.codfilial
FROM
VLIMITECREDITO a
INNER JOIN
PCCLIENT b on (a.idparceiro = b.codcli)
INNER JOIN
PCPREST C on (b.codcli = c.codeli)
WHERE c.codfilial = 11 AND c.dtpag IS NULL
GROUP BY 
b.codeli,
b.cliente,
c.codusur,
Gc.codsupervisor,
c.codfilial
```

Recomendo que você pesquise por GROUP BY. Algumas leituras para você:
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-group-by/
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Espero que tenha te ajudado.

[]s

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente entendi o conceito do group by, obrigado!

Comment: Show de Bola! Fico feliz em ter ajudado.